Multiprocessing with python being slower than without
I have been trying to learn multiprocessing. I wanted to test my understanding by making a little program that would generate a list of random numbers. Then make two different methods to find the largest number in the list. The first method not using multiprocessing and the second using multiprocessing. However when I run the code the runtime is always hundreds of times slower when I use the multiprocessing code regardless of the length of the list.
import random
import multiprocessing
import time

def random_num_list(length=100000):
     return [random.randint(-13443,435234) for i in range(length)]

rando_list = random_num_list()

def method1(lst):
    biggest_num = -13443
    for i in lst:
        if i > biggest_num:
            biggest_num = i

    return biggest_num

lst1, lst2 = rando_list[:int(len(rando_list)/3)], rando_list[int(len(rando_list)/3):]

def partial_process(lst1, lst2):
    biggest_num = -13443
    for i in lst1:
        if i > biggest_num:
            biggest_num = i

    lst2.append(biggest_num)
    #print("New record added!\n")

def full_process(lst2):
    biggest_num = -13443
    for i in lst2:
        if i > biggest_num:
            biggest_num = i

    print(biggest_num)

def method2(lst1,lst2):
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        lst2 = manager.list(lst2)

        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=partial_process,args=(lst1, lst2))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=full_process,args=(lst2,))

        p1.start()
        p1.join()

        p2.start()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method2(lst1,lst2)
    print(method1(rando_list))

I also tried writing method2 like this as well:
def method2(lst):
    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  # Number of processes to match the number of CPU cores
    chunk_size = len(lst) // num_processes

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
        # Split the list into chunks and process in parallel
        results = pool.map(find_max, [lst[i * chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size] for i in range(num_processes)])

    return max(results)


To run p1 and p2 in parallel, both start calls must be before the join calls.

If you aren't using Linux, you should also move the assignments to variables rando_list, lst1, lst2 into the if __name__ == '__main__' guard.

Disabling parallel execution is obviously the fault here. Apart from that, consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com, make sure that you read their site guidelines first though.

"Then make two different methods to find the largest number in the list." that is precisely the sort of thing multiprocessing will not be faster at. finding the max is fast, faster than the overhead of serializing the data, sending that data to the subprocess, deserializing it in the subprocess, then serializing and sending the answer back

You should be using map() for this.
Let's go through it:
from random import randint
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import sys

N = 100_000
NCHUNKS = 2

def getmax(_list: list[int]) -> int:
    # could obviously use built-in max() function which would be faster
    # but we want the process to (artificially) use more CPU than is actually necessary
    _max = -(sys.maxsize - 1)
    for n in _list:
        if n > _max:
            _max = n
    return _max


def main():
    _list = [randint(-13443, 435234) for _ in range(N)]
    chunk = len(_list) // NCHUNKS
    lo, hi = 0, chunk
    args = []
    for _ in range(NCHUNKS-1):
        args.append(_list[lo:hi])
        lo, hi = hi, hi + chunk
    args.append(_list[lo:])
    with Pool() as pool:
        # args is a list with references to each chunk of the data list
        results = pool.map(getmax, args)
        # therefore results will be a list containing NCHUNKS ints - one from each of the subprocesses
        m = max(results)
        print(m)
        assert m == max(_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Duration = {end-start:.2f}s")

Output:
Duration = 0.11s


Interesting, thanks for the insight. I'm still getting the same runtime however and the regular code without multiprocessing is 0.0025 and often faster.

@FsksksksssSsksksksksksksk That's because the overhead of creating subprocesses outweighs the processing time of the getmax() function. Don't use multiprocessing just because you can - it's not always appropriate and it certainly isn't in this case

That makes sense. What are good use cases for multiprocessing? I'm just trying to learn more about it and test my knowledge.
